# Very Slow Download Speed in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, wireless, realtek-wireless

The issue I'm having is extremely slow download speeds (<1.0 Mb/s) through my WiFi while running Ubuntu 16.04. I've checked all the obvious. I've run the script from GitHub (wifi-info.txt), and pasted the results to the Ubuntu pastebin. http://paste.ubuntu.com/23962808/

This only happens when I run Ubuntu 16.04 on my laptop, and seems to affect the WiFi for all devices connected to my wireless router (Linksys AC2600, Model# EA8500) while Ubuntu 16.04 is connected to it. When I shut down Ubuntu, the WiFi speeds return to normal. Can someone please help me?

Comment: RTL8187SE is b/g only. It will slow down the network especially if the wireless encryption settings are any other than WPA2-AES. Your script is incomplete. We can see the it is using WPA2 only, no mix mode (good) but the rest of the script contains among other informations the details about the wireless profiles where we could check whether it's using AES (good) or TKIP (very bad and deprecated in the 2012 revision of the 802.11 standard).

Comment: The output of the script says it creates a .tar zip file as well if the file turns out to be bigger than a certain size. Would the rest of the info you're looking for be in this zip file?

Comment: Probably and now you know what to check for. And those settings are at your router anyway.

Comment: It's definitely using WPA2-AES.

Comment: Would it have something to do with the IPV6 settings somewhere in Ubuntu?

Comment: Automatic for IPV4 and IPV6 usually works. Keep in mind that to some extend a b/g device always slows down a faster network. Encryption settings are the usual culprit so we check that first but the performance also  varies noticeably depending on the router and other devices and different OSes drivers may and often do perform differently with the same hardware. BTW, are you dual booting? If so what's different when you use Windows and the WiFi?

Comment: Yes, dual booting Ubuntu and Win10. WiFi works fine with everything else. It's only when I boot into Ubuntu that I lose download speed - substantially. Slows to a crawl, and affects speed for any other device that's connected to the router. When I shut down Ubuntu, everything returns to normal. Never had this problem in Ubuntu before a certain update a few months ago.